# cyclic subnormal subgroups in a semi-direct product

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=BA$ be a semidirect product of subgroups $A$ and $B$ with $A$ normal in $G$.
We know that if $S$ is a subnormal subgroup of $B$, then $SA$ is a subnormal subnormal subgroup of G.

My Question is: If $S$ is a cyclic subnormal subgroup of $B$, then is it true
that $SA$ will be a cyclic subnormal subgroup of G?

Comment: Well, if $S=B$ is cyclic then it fails, e.g. $G=S_n$, $A=A_n$ and $B$ is any cyclic subgroup generated by a transposition. Right? Actually this does not seem to be true for any non-abelian semidirect product with $B$ cyclic.

Comment: I am almost certain this exact question was asked a few weeks back. Is this from some set of exercises in a book?

Comment: @freakish, Let $G=BA$ be a semidirect product of subgroups $A$ and $B$  of coprime order,
with $A$ normal in $G$. 

Now if $S$ is a cyclic subnormal subgroup of $B$, and $A'$ is a cyclic subnormal subgroup of $A$ then is it true
that $SA'$ will be a cyclic subnormal subgroup of G?

Comment: @Tobias, its not from the exercise of a book, infact its a research problem, as I am working on the subnormal structure of a finite group

Comment: Then you ought to have tried some examples, as these products are almost never cyclic.

Comment: @FazliAmin Again if both $A,B$ are cyclic and $G$ is not (i.e. the semidirect product is not direct) then the statement is false. Orders don't matter. For coprime example look at $S_3$ - the semidirect product of two cyclic groups of order $2$ and $3$.

Comment: @ freakish, Thanks, your explanation help me a lot. From the last comment, what I guess, that its converse is true, i.e
if $H$ is a cyclic subnormal subgroup of $G=BA$, then $H=SA'$, 
and $S$ would be a cyclic subnormal subgroup of $B$, and $A'$ a cyclic subnormal subgroup of $A$.

Comment: @FazliAmin nope. Take $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the diagonal $\Delta$. That subgroup is not a product of any subgroups of direct components. Bad luck.